# D-Link DWM-157 3G USB Modem doesn't connect

Tags: networking, raspberry-pi, internet, modem

I want to connect to the internet using D-Link DWM-157 3G USB Modem, with Raspberry Pi 3 and Raspbian Jessie as OS (latest version).
I've tried billions of methods without success!!

This is so far where I have gone:

Fortunately, the modem has been switched to **modem mode**, and lsusb confirms that. Also, it has registered 4 ttyUSB devices, ttyUSB0~3.
Now, the internet icon at the top-right corner of the desktop with two top-down arrows, is blinking, which probably means it's trying to connect (but no success!)

I've tried to connect with ***wvdial*** and also ***sakis3g***.

The following is ***/etc/wvdial.conf*** :

```
[Dialer Defaults]
Init1 = ATZ
Init2 = ATQ0 V1 E1 S0=0 &C1 &D2 +FCLASS=0
Init3 = AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","mcinet"
Stupid Mode = 1
Modem Type = Analog Modem
Baud = 9600
New PPPD = yes
Modem = /dev/ttyUSB0
ISDN = 0
Phone = *99#
Username = { }
Password = { }
```

and also the following is ***/etc/sakis3g.conf*** :

```
APN="mcinet"
```

Here are the output:

***sudo wvdial***

```
....
....
Modem initialized.
Sending ATDT*99#
Waiting for carrier.
ATDT*99#
ERROR
OK
Invalid dial command.
Disconnecting at .....
```

and also:

***sudo ./sakis3g --interactive***

```
......
Preparing Modem ...
Registering Network ...
Modem unable to register a network.
```

So, what should I do!?
Any help is highly appreciated.

---

***Edit1***: I've tried this modem on Win7, and it works without problem.

---

***Edit2***: The following is the debug log of sakis3g:

```
pi@raspberrypi:/usr/bin/modem3g $ sudo ./sakis3g connect --pppd --debug

-------------------------------------------
Sakis3G 0.2.0e running on DEBUG mode.
-------------------------------------------
Sun 30 Apr 21:56:11 IRDT 2017
-------------------------------------------
Command line was: /tmp/sakis3gz.20928.sakis3g "connect" "--pppd" "--debug"
Running with PID: 20958
-------------------------------------------
Environment is:
DEBUG='on'
DESKTOP=''
DISPLAY=':0.0'
EXTRACTED='/tmp/sakis3gz.20928.sakis3g'
HOME='/root'
IFS='   
'
LANG='en_GB.UTF-8'
LOGNAME='root'
LS_COLORS='rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.axv=01;35:*.anx=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.axa=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:'
MAIL='/var/mail/root'
MEGZ='./sakis3g'
MYVERSION='0.2.0e'
NOFUNCNAME='1'
OPTIND='1'
PATH='/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin'
PPID='20928'
PROVIDER='./sakis3g'
PS1='# '
PS2='> '
PS4='+ '
PWD='/usr/bin/modem3g'
SHELL='/bin/bash'
SUDO_COMMAND='./sakis3g connect --pppd --debug'
SUDO_GID='1000'
SUDO_UID='1000'
SUDO_USER='pi'
TERM='xterm'
TRAPS='cleanscreen '
USER='root'
USERNAME='root'
XAUTHORITY='/home/pi/.Xauthority'
allargs='"connect" "--pppd" "--debug"'
binaryvariable='grep'
cutbin='/usr/bin/cut'
direct_pppd='yes'
grepbin='/bin/grep'
lastverbosetext='Starting up'
me='/tmp/sakis3gz.20928.sakis3g'
printfbin='/usr/bin/printf'
sedbin='/bin/sed'
trbin='/usr/bin/tr'
verbosecurrentcount='7'
whichbin='/bin/which'
-------------------------------------------
Will now proceed with Sakis3G execution.
-------------------------------------------
[20958] [21:56:11] Located "echo" within PATH (/bin/echo).
[20958] [21:56:11] Level 1 dependencies met.
[20958] [21:56:11] Dir "/bin" exists in PATH.
[20958] [21:56:11] Dir "/usr/bin" exists in PATH.
[20958] [21:56:11] Dir "/sbin" exists in PATH.
[20958] [21:56:11] Dir "/usr/sbin" exists in PATH.
[20958] [21:56:11] Done setting up PATH.
[20958] [21:56:11] Located "readlink" within PATH (/bin/readlink).
[20958] [21:56:11] My location is "/usr/bin/modem3g/sakis3g".
[20958] [21:56:11] Located "wc" within PATH (/usr/bin/wc).
[20958] [21:56:12] Located "cat" within PATH (/bin/cat).
[20958] [21:56:12] Located "tail" within PATH (/usr/bin/tail).
[20958] [21:56:12] Located "head" within PATH (/usr/bin/head).
[20958] [21:56:12] Located "sort" within PATH (/usr/bin/sort).
[20958] [21:56:12] Located "uniq" within PATH (/usr/bin/uniq).
[20958] [21:56:12] Located "ls" within PATH (/bin/ls).
[20958] [21:56:12] Located "setsid" within PATH (/usr/bin/setsid).
[20958] [21:56:12] Located "getent" within PATH (/usr/bin/getent).
[20958] [21:56:12] Located "ps" within PATH (/bin/ps).
[20958] [21:56:12] Located "chmod" within PATH (/bin/chmod).
[20958] [21:56:12] Located "chown" within PATH (/bin/chown).
[20958] [21:56:12] Located "touch" within PATH (/bin/touch).
[20958] [21:56:12] Located "expr" within PATH (/usr/bin/expr).
[20958] [21:56:12] Located "seq" within PATH (/usr/bin/seq).
[20958] [21:56:12] Located "cp" within PATH (/bin/cp).
[20958] [21:56:12] Located "rm" within PATH (/bin/rm).
[20958] [21:56:12] Located "who" within PATH (/usr/bin/who).
[20958] [21:56:12] Located "mv" within PATH (/bin/mv).
[20958] [21:56:12] Located "basename" within PATH (/usr/bin/basename).
[20958] [21:56:12] Located "dirname" within PATH (/usr/bin/dirname).
[20958] [21:56:12] Level 2 dependencies met.
[20958] [21:56:12] Basic binaries are resolved.
[20958] [21:56:12] Parent process is: sudo
[20958] [21:56:12] Running by user request.
[20958] [21:56:12] Person behind screen is pi.
[20958] [21:56:12] Configuration file /etc/default/sakis3g does not exist or is not readable.
[20958] [21:56:12] Configuration file /etc/sysconfig/sakis3g does not exist or is not readable.
[20958] [21:56:12] Loading system-wide configuration file /etc/sakis3g.conf.
/-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[20958] [21:56:12] Will now display contents of: \'/etc/sakis3g.conf\'
/-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
OTHER=CUSTOM_TTY
CUSTOM_TTY="/dev/ttyUSB0"
APN=CUSTOM_APN
CUSTOM_APN="mcinet"
APN_USER="a"
APN_PASS="a"
SIM_PIN="3436"
\-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 119 Apr 30 21:39 /etc/sakis3g.conf
\-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[20958] [21:56:12] Configuration arguments are: "OTHER=CUSTOM_TTY" "CUSTOM_TTY=/dev/ttyUSB0" "APN=CUSTOM_APN" "CUSTOM_APN=mcinet" "APN_USER=a" "APN_PASS=a" "SIM_PIN=3436" 
[20958] [21:56:12] Parsing configuration value: OTHER=CUSTOM_TTY.
[20958] [21:56:12] Command line set variable OTHER to "CUSTOM_TTY".
[20958] [21:56:12] Parsing configuration value: CUSTOM_TTY=/dev/ttyUSB0.
[20958] [21:56:13] Command line set variable CUSTOM_TTY to "/dev/ttyUSB0".
[20958] [21:56:13] Parsing configuration value: APN=CUSTOM_APN.
[20958] [21:56:13] Command line set variable APN to "CUSTOM_APN".
[20958] [21:56:13] Parsing configuration value: CUSTOM_APN=mcinet.
[20958] [21:56:13] Command line set variable CUSTOM_APN to "mcinet".
[20958] [21:56:13] Parsing configuration value: APN_USER=a.
[20958] [21:56:13] Command line set variable APN_USER to "a".
[20958] [21:56:13] Parsing configuration value: APN_PASS=a.
[20958] [21:56:13] Command line set variable APN_PASS to "a".
[20958] [21:56:13] Parsing configuration value: SIM_PIN=3436.
[20958] [21:56:13] Command line set variable SIM_PIN to "3436".
[20958] [21:56:13] Finished loading file /etc/sakis3g.conf.
[20958] [21:56:13] Configuration file(s) loaded.
[20958] [21:56:13] Will attempt to get access to display :0.
[20958] [21:56:13] Located "xauth" within PATH (/usr/bin/xauth).
[20958] [21:56:13] Already granted access to display :0.
[20958] [21:56:13] Will be using display :0.
[20958] [21:56:13] Selecting GUI.
[20958] [21:56:13] Unable to locate "kdialog" within PATH.
[20958] [21:56:13] Located "zenity" within PATH (/usr/bin/zenity).
[20958] [21:56:13] zenity selected as GUI.
[20958] [21:56:13] Locale en_GB.UTF-8 found in environment.
[20958] [21:56:13] Will attempt to get translation file from package: messages/en_GB.UTF-8.
[20958] [21:56:13] Loaded default value for foldwrapping: 60
[20958] [21:56:13] No translations retrieved from file. Will not be using translations.
[20958] [21:56:13] Loaded default value for foldwrapping: 60
[20958] [21:56:13] Located "ifconfig" within PATH (/sbin/ifconfig).
[20958] [21:56:13] Root level dependencies met.
[20958] [21:56:13] Loading Usb-ModeSwitch device database.
[20958] [21:56:13] Embedded device database loaded.
[20958] [21:56:13] Switchable devices within embedded device database:
0421:0610 0471:1210 0471:1237 0482:024d 04e8:f000 057c:84ff 05c6:1000 05c6:2001 05c6:f000 072f:100d 0930:0d46 0ace:2011 0ace:20ff 0af0:6711 0af0:6731 0af0:6751 0af0:6771 0af0:6791 0af0:6811 0af0:6911 0af0:6951 0af0:6971 0af0:7011 0af0:7031 0af0:7051 0af0:7071 0af0:7111 0af0:7211 0af0:7251 0af0:7271 0af0:7301 0af0:7311 0af0:7361 0af0:7381 0af0:7401 0af0:7501 0af0:7601 0af0:7701 0af0:7801 0af0:7901 0af0:8200 0af0:8201 0af0:8300 0af0:8302 0af0:8304 0af0:8400 0af0:c031 0af0:c100 0af0:d013 0af0:d031 0af0:d033 0af0:d035 0af0:d055 0af0:d057 0af0:d058 0af0:d155 0af0:d157 0af0:d255 0af0:d257 0af0:d357 0b3c:c700 0fce:d0cf 0fce:d0e1 0fce:d103 1004:1000 1004:607f 1004:613a 1004:613f 1033:0035 106c:3b03 106c:3b06 1076:7f40 1199:0fff 1266:1000 12d1:1001 12d1:1003 12d1:101e 12d1:1414 12d1:1446 12d1:1520 12d1:1521 12d1:1557 1410:5010 1410:5020 1410:5030 1410:5031 1410:5041 148f:2578 16d8:6803 16d8:700a 16d8:f000 198f:bccd 19d2:0003 19d2:0026 19d2:0040 19d2:0053 19d2:0083 19d2:0101 19d2:0103 19d2:0115 19d2:1001 19d2:1007 19d2:1009 19d2:2000 19d2:fff5 19d2:fff6 1a8d:1000 1ab7:5700 1b7d:0700 1bbb:f000 1c9e:1001 1c9e:9200 1c9e:f000 1dd6:1000 1e0e:f000 1f28:0021 1fac:0130
[20958] [21:56:13] Switched devices within embedded device database:
0421:0612 0471:1206 0471:1234 04e8:6601 057c:8401 05c6:9000 072f:90cc 0930:0d45 0af0:6600 0af0:6701 0af0:6901 0b3c:c000 0b3c:c001 0b3c:c002 1004:6114 1004:6124 1004:6141 106c:3715 106c:3717 1076:7f00 1199:0017 1199:0018 1199:0019 1199:0020 1199:0021 1199:0022 1199:0024 1199:0026 1199:0027 1199:0028 1199:0029 1199:0112 1199:0120 1199:0218 1199:0220 1199:0224 1199:6802 1199:6803 1199:6804 1199:6805 1199:6808 1199:6809 1199:6812 1199:6813 1199:6815 1199:6816 1199:6820 1199:6821 1199:6822 1199:6832 1199:6833 1199:6834 1199:6835 1199:6838 1199:6839 1199:683a 1199:683b 1199:683c 1199:683d 1199:683e 1199:6850 1199:6851 1199:6852 1199:6853 1199:6855 1199:6856 1199:6859 1199:685a 1266:1002 1266:1003 1266:1004 1266:1005 1266:1006 1266:1007 1266:1008 1266:1009 1266:100a 1266:100b 1266:100c 1266:100d 1266:100e 1266:100f 1266:1011 1266:1012 12d1:1001 12d1:1003 12d1:1406 12d1:140c 12d1:141b 12d1:1464 12d1:1465 12d1:14a5 12d1:14ac 1410:4100 1410:4400 1410:6000 1410:6002 1410:7001 1410:7003 148f:9021 16d5:6502 16d8:6006 16d8:680a 198f:0220 19d2:0001 19d2:0002 19d2:0015 19d2:0016 19d2:0017 19d2:0022 19d2:0031 19d2:0037 19d2:0052 19d2:0055 19d2:0063 19d2:0064 19d2:0094 19d2:0104 19d2:0116 19d2:0124 19d2:0128 19d2:1003 19d2:1008 19d2:1010 19d2:fff1 19d2:ffff 1a8d:1002 1a8d:1009 1ab7:5731 1b7d:0001 1bbb:0000 1c9e:6061 1c9e:9000 1c9e:9063 1c9e:9202 1c9e:9603 1dbc:0005 1dd6:1002 1e0e:9000 1e0e:9200 1e0e:ce16 1e0e:cefe 1f28:0020 1fac:0131 1fe7:0100
[20958] [21:56:13] Embedded Usb-ModeSwitch device database contains 260 entries.
[20958] [21:56:13] Folder "/etc/usb_modeswitch.d" exists. Will check if it contains configuration files.
[20958] [21:56:13] Loading system supplied device database.
[20958] [21:56:14] Switchable devices within system device database:

[20958] [21:56:14] Switched devices within system device database:

[20958] [21:56:14] Finished starting up.
[20958] [21:56:14] Loaded default value for pppint: ppp0
[20958] [21:56:14] Verbosing: 7% Locating device
[20958] [21:56:14] Located "kill" within PATH (/bin/kill).
[20958] [21:56:14] Establishing zenity verbose helper.
/-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[20958] [21:56:14] Will now run command: \'/bin/touch /tmp/sakis3g.zenity.pipe\'
/-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[20958] [21:56:14] Command returned 0.
\-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
/-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[20958] [21:56:14] Will now run command: \'/bin/chmod 666 /tmp/sakis3g.zenity.pipe\'
/-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[20958] [21:56:14] Command returned 0.
\-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[20958] [21:56:14] PID 22151 is still running.
[20958] [21:56:14] Fetching connected USB devices by using "/sys/bus/usb/devices".
[20958] [21:56:14] Connected USB devices are:
0424:9514:BUSNUM=001
0424:ec00:BUSNUM=001
1a2c:0c21:USB Keyboard
1d6b:0002:DWC OTG Controller
2001:7d0e:D-Link DWM-157
214b:7000:USB2.0 HUB
2188:0ae1:USB OPTICAL MOUSE

** (zenity:22151): WARNING **: Error retrieving accessibility bus address: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.a11y.Bus was not provided by any .service files
[20958] [21:56:14] No plugged modems found.
[20958] [21:56:14] Asking user to select: OTHER Please select modem type Select modem category that best fits your 3G modem. Select Cancel USBMODEM USB device BLUETOOTH Bluetooth modem CUSTOM_TTY Custom tty...
[20958] [21:56:14] Asking user to select: OTHER Please select modem type Select modem category that best fits your 3G modem. Select Cancel USBMODEM USB device BLUETOOTH Bluetooth modem CUSTOM_TTY Custom tty...
[20958] [21:56:14] OTHER=CUSTOM_TTY
[20958] [21:56:14] USBMODEM!=CUSTOM_TTY
[20958] [21:56:14] BLUETOOTH!=CUSTOM_TTY
[20958] [21:56:14] CUSTOM_TTY==CUSTOM_TTY.
[20958] [21:56:14] User has already selected OTHER="CUSTOM_TTY". Returning 3.
[20958] [21:56:14] Asking user to enter: CUSTOM_TTY Please enter tty Enter tty node where your 3G modem resides, or leave empty to abort OK Cancel
[20958] [21:56:14] Asking user to enter: CUSTOM_TTY Please enter tty Enter tty node where your 3G modem resides, or leave empty to abort OK Cancel
[20958] [21:56:14] CUSTOM_TTY=/dev/ttyUSB0
[20958] [21:56:14] User has already entered CUSTOM_TTY="/dev/ttyUSB0". Returning 0.
[20958] [21:56:14] Using device node "/dev/ttyUSB0".
[20958] [21:56:14] Setting up modem.
[20958] [21:56:14] We are root already. Proceeding.
[20958] [21:56:14] Setting up custom modem on /dev/ttyUSB0.
Gtk-Message: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.
[20958] [21:56:14] Attempting to setup custom tty modem on "/dev/ttyUSB0".
[20958] [21:56:14] Custom tty "/dev/ttyUSB0" exists. Nothing more to do for setting it up.
[20958] [21:56:14] Modem is now setup and resides on /dev/ttyUSB0.
[20958] [21:56:14] Located "wvdial" within PATH (/usr/bin/wvdial).
[20958] [21:56:14] Located "pppd" within PATH (/usr/sbin/pppd).
[20958] [21:56:15] Loaded default value for PPPD_PEERS: /etc/ppp/peers
[20958] [21:56:15] Located "chat" within PATH (/usr/sbin/chat).
[20958] [21:56:15] Verbosing: 14% Preparing modem
[20958] [21:56:15] PID 22151 is still running.
[20958] [21:56:15] PID 22151 is still running.
[20958] [21:56:15] Loaded default value for CHAT_ABORT_STRINGS: ABORT BUSY ABORT ERROR ABORT BLOCKED ABORT NOCARRIER
[20958] [21:56:15] Unknown command "STAGE0".
[20958] [21:56:15] Command "PROBEGSM" refers to AT commands: ATI OK 'AT+GCAP' OK 'AT+CGSN' OK
[20958] [21:56:15] Will send PROBEGSM commands to tty /dev/ttyUSB0: "" '\pAT' OK ATI OK 'AT+GCAP' OK 'AT+CGSN' OK '\pAT' OK
[20958] [21:56:15] We are root already. Proceeding.
[20958] [21:56:15] Device /dev/ttyUSB0 is not busy.
[20958] [21:56:15] Got response from tty:


OK



MTK2

MOLY.WR8.W1244.DNR.WG.MP.V7



OK



+GCAP: +FCLASS, +CGSM



OK



355621056029709



OK



OK
[20958] [21:56:15] Found GSM capabilities on tty /dev/ttyUSB0.
[20958] [21:56:15] Command "IDENTIFY" refers to AT commands: AT+CGMM OK
[20958] [21:56:15] Will send IDENTIFY commands to tty /dev/ttyUSB0: "" '\pAT' OK AT+CGMM OK '\pAT' OK
[20958] [21:56:15] We are root already. Proceeding.
[20958] [21:56:15] Device /dev/ttyUSB0 is not busy.
[20958] [21:56:15] Got response from tty:


OK



+CGMM: MTK2



OK



OK
[20958] [21:56:16] Modem on tty identified itself as: +CGMM: MTK2
[20958] [21:56:16] No information found for  within files/modem_init.db database.
[20958] [21:56:16] Unknown command "STAGE1".
[20958] [21:56:16] Using default PINCHECK.
[20958] [21:56:16] Command "PINCHECK" refers to AT commands: 'AT+CPIN?' OK
[20958] [21:56:16] Will send PINCHECK commands to tty /dev/ttyUSB0: "" '\pAT' OK 'AT+CPIN?' OK '\pAT' OK
[20958] [21:56:16] We are root already. Proceeding.
[20958] [21:56:16] Device /dev/ttyUSB0 is not busy.
[20958] [21:56:16] Got response from tty:


OK



+CPIN: READY



OK



OK
[20958] [21:56:16] Modem on /dev/ttyUSB0 does not need PIN.
[20958] [21:56:16] Unknown command "STAGE4".
[20958] [21:56:16] Command "OPERATOR" refers to AT commands: AT+COPS=3,2 OK 'AT+COPS?' OK
[20958] [21:56:16] Will send OPERATOR commands to tty /dev/ttyUSB0: "" '\pAT' OK AT+COPS=3,2 OK 'AT+COPS?' OK '\pAT' OK
[20958] [21:56:16] We are root already. Proceeding.
[20958] [21:56:16] Device /dev/ttyUSB0 is not busy.
[20958] [21:56:17] Got response from tty:


OK



OK



+COPS: 0



OK



OK
[20958] [21:56:17] Modem not registered to a network yet.
[20958] [21:56:17] Waiting modem to register network (4 seconds).
[20958] [21:56:17] Verbosing: 21% Registering network
[20958] [21:56:17] PID 22151 is still running.
[20958] [21:56:17] PID 22151 is still running.
[20958] [21:56:21] Command "OPERATOR" refers to AT commands: AT+COPS=3,2 OK 'AT+COPS?' OK
[20958] [21:56:21] Will send OPERATOR commands to tty /dev/ttyUSB0: "" '\pAT' OK AT+COPS=3,2 OK 'AT+COPS?' OK '\pAT' OK
[20958] [21:56:21] We are root already. Proceeding.
[20958] [21:56:21] Device /dev/ttyUSB0 is not busy.
[20958] [21:56:21] Got response from tty:


OK



OK



+COPS: 0



OK



OK
[20958] [21:56:21] Modem not registered to a network yet.
[20958] [21:56:21] Waiting modem to register network (8 seconds).
[20958] [21:56:21] Verbosing: 22% Registering network
[20958] [21:56:21] PID 22151 is still running.
[20958] [21:56:21] PID 22151 is still running.
[20958] [21:56:25] Command "OPERATOR" refers to AT commands: AT+COPS=3,2 OK 'AT+COPS?' OK
[20958] [21:56:25] Will send OPERATOR commands to tty /dev/ttyUSB0: "" '\pAT' OK AT+COPS=3,2 OK 'AT+COPS?' OK '\pAT' OK
[20958] [21:56:25] We are root already. Proceeding.
[20958] [21:56:26] Device /dev/ttyUSB0 is not busy.
[20958] [21:56:26] Got response from tty:


OK



OK



+COPS: 0



OK



OK
[20958] [21:56:26] Modem not registered to a network yet.
[20958] [21:56:26] Waiting modem to register network (12 seconds).
[20958] [21:56:26] Verbosing: 23% Registering network
[20958] [21:56:26] PID 22151 is still running.
[20958] [21:56:26] PID 22151 is still running.
[20958] [21:56:30] Command "OPERATOR" refers to AT commands: AT+COPS=3,2 OK 'AT+COPS?' OK
[20958] [21:56:30] Will send OPERATOR commands to tty /dev/ttyUSB0: "" '\pAT' OK AT+COPS=3,2 OK 'AT+COPS?' OK '\pAT' OK
[20958] [21:56:30] We are root already. Proceeding.
[20958] [21:56:30] Device /dev/ttyUSB0 is not busy.
[20958] [21:56:30] Got response from tty:


OK



OK



+COPS: 0



OK



OK
[20958] [21:56:30] Modem not registered to a network yet.
[20958] [21:56:30] Waiting modem to register network (16 seconds).
[20958] [21:56:31] Verbosing: 24% Registering network
[20958] [21:56:31] PID 22151 is still running.
[20958] [21:56:31] PID 22151 is still running.
[20958] [21:56:35] Command "OPERATOR" refers to AT commands: AT+COPS=3,2 OK 'AT+COPS?' OK
[20958] [21:56:35] Will send OPERATOR commands to tty /dev/ttyUSB0: "" '\pAT' OK AT+COPS=3,2 OK 'AT+COPS?' OK '\pAT' OK
[20958] [21:56:35] We are root already. Proceeding.
[20958] [21:56:35] Device /dev/ttyUSB0 is not busy.
[20958] [21:56:35] Got response from tty:


OK



OK



+COPS: 0



OK



OK
[20958] [21:56:35] Modem not registered to a network yet.
[20958] [21:56:35] Waiting modem to register network (20 seconds).
[20958] [21:56:35] Verbosing: 25% Registering network
[20958] [21:56:35] PID 22151 is still running.
[20958] [21:56:35] PID 22151 is still running.
[20958] [21:56:39] Command "OPERATOR" refers to AT commands: AT+COPS=3,2 OK 'AT+COPS?' OK
[20958] [21:56:39] Will send OPERATOR commands to tty /dev/ttyUSB0: "" '\pAT' OK AT+COPS=3,2 OK 'AT+COPS?' OK '\pAT' OK
[20958] [21:56:39] We are root already. Proceeding.
[20958] [21:56:39] Device /dev/ttyUSB0 is not busy.
[20958] [21:56:40] Got response from tty:


OK



OK



+COPS: 0



OK



OK
[20958] [21:56:40] Modem not registered to a network yet.
[20958] [21:56:40] Waiting modem to register network (24 seconds).
[20958] [21:56:40] Verbosing: 26% Registering network
[20958] [21:56:40] PID 22151 is still running.
[20958] [21:56:40] PID 22151 is still running.
[20958] [21:56:44] Command "OPERATOR" refers to AT commands: AT+COPS=3,2 OK 'AT+COPS?' OK
[20958] [21:56:44] Will send OPERATOR commands to tty /dev/ttyUSB0: "" '\pAT' OK AT+COPS=3,2 OK 'AT+COPS?' OK '\pAT' OK
[20958] [21:56:44] We are root already. Proceeding.
[20958] [21:56:44] Device /dev/ttyUSB0 is not busy.
[20958] [21:56:44] Got response from tty:


OK



OK



+COPS: 0



OK



OK
[20958] [21:56:44] Modem not registered to a network yet.
[20958] [21:56:44] Giving up after 24 seconds have passed.
[20958] [21:56:44] Error: Modem unable to register a network.
/-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[20958] [21:56:44] Will now run command: \'/bin/rm -f /tmp/sakis3g.zenity.pipe\'
/-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[20958] [21:56:44] Command returned 0.
\-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[20958] [21:56:45] PID 22151 is not running any more.
[20958] [21:56:45] PID 22151 is not running any more.

** (zenity:23125): WARNING **: Error retrieving accessibility bus address: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.a11y.Bus was not provided by any .service files
Gtk-Message: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.
[20958] [21:59:23] Asking user to confirm: scan Scan for network Modem was unable to register a network. Would you like to manually select a network? Yes No reset
[20958] [21:59:23] Asking user to confirm: scan Scan for network Modem was unable to register a network. Would you like to manually select a network? Yes No reset
[20958] [21:59:23] Prompting user to select yesscan or noscan.
[20958] [21:59:24] User selected "no" (1).
[20958] [21:59:24] User answered "no".
[20958] [21:59:24] Error: Failed to connect.

** (zenity:23207): WARNING **: Error retrieving accessibility bus address: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.a11y.Bus was not provided by any .service files
Gtk-Message: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.
[20958] [21:59:26] Aborting execution chain due to actor "connect" returning 13.
[20958] [21:59:26] Following actors executed: connect
[20958] [21:59:26] Verbosing: 33% Cleaning
[20958] [21:59:26] Establishing zenity verbose helper.
/-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[20958] [21:59:26] Will now run command: \'/bin/touch /tmp/sakis3g.zenity.pipe\'
/-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[20958] [21:59:26] Command returned 0.
\-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
/-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[20958] [21:59:26] Will now run command: \'/bin/chmod 666 /tmp/sakis3g.zenity.pipe\'
/-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[20958] [21:59:26] Command returned 0.
\-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[20958] [21:59:26] PID 23301 is still running.
[20958] [21:59:26] Stopping operation with return status: 13
[20958] [21:59:26] Now executing traps.
[20958] [21:59:26] Executing trap "cleanscreen".
/-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[20958] [21:59:26] Will now run command: \'/bin/rm -f /tmp/sakis3g.zenity.pipe\'
/-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[20958] [21:59:26] Command returned 0.
\-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[20958] [21:59:27] PID 23301 is still running.
[20958] [21:59:27] PID 23301 is still running.
```

Comment: Any suggestions !?

Comment: Install the `modem-manager-gui` package : `sudo apt install modem-manager-gui` ,  connect your usb modem and start the gui with `modem-manager-gui` command

Comment: Thanks @GAD3R for your comment. I tried `modem-manager-gui`, but no help.